# PHP / MySql: How to store Select results in temporary array to fetch single items from there

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, select

I am a complete beginner to PHP and MySQL and hope someone can help me with this.

I have a MySql db with a table "`TranslationsMain`" and the following PHP query. 
This returns all the items from column "`en`" in the db table and works correctly so far.

Instead of echoing the whole list (I just did this here for testing), **how can I echo only a specific item from the column resp. from the query results**, e.g. the fifth item ?
I could also add an ID column for this to my db table if that helps.

**Note:** 
The login variables to establish the connection are declared separately in my header file.

**My PHP:**

```
<?php 
    require_once("includes/header.php");

    $tblTranslations = "TranslationsMain";  

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tblTranslations;
    $translations = $conn->query($sql);
    if($translations->num_rows > 0){
        echo "<table><tr><th>Translations</th></tr>";
        while($translation = $translations->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<tr><td>" . $translation["en"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }else{
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

**Update:**
This is not a duplicate of the other question posted in the comments. 
What I am looking for here is a way to fetch all data at once on page load and save it temporarily so that I can then just refer to the temporary storage from within the page instead of having to call the db multiple times.
**A possible solution could be map / key (see Goikiu's comment below).**

Many thanks in advance, 
Mike

Comment: You can change the query or put an if-then(-else) statement

Comment: use  count and increment the count then check the if condition

Comment: @Goikiu: Thanks - and if/then wouldn't help me here as I need to get various different items this way across the page. So e.g. there is a div where I want to echo the fifth item and another div where I want to echo the 10th item etc.

Comment: @Ramki: Thanks for this ! This sounds good but is there a way I can do this only once and then save it in an array etc. so that within the page I can refer to this array instead of querying the db multiple times ?

Comment: @keewee279 that's wrong. One specific value equal to one query, that's a good solution, so make two query (example) and use the result for what you need, make em dynamic so that you can call them 200 time if necessary

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL WHERE statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838186/sql-where-statement)

Comment: @bodi0: Thanks - I don't think this is a duplicate of what you posted here - please see my comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit your Query; right now you are selecting all values.
Edit it in a way you only get the right results. e.g.:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tblTranslations . "WHERE ColumnID = 6";
```

The WHERE statement is what reduces/filters the amount results and thats what you're missing.

Comment: Thanks for this ! This sounds good but is there a way I can do this only once and then save it in an array etc. so that within the page I can refer to this array instead of querying the db multiple times ?

Comment: @keewee279 what you're suggesting is bad programming practice

Comment: @KarsBarendrecht he can use even IN statement to have multiple value ;)

Comment: @All: Thanks for your help ! Since I am new to this I am not sure I understand it right. Say I need to echo 10 items across my page wouldnt it be better to fetch all the data at the beginning of the page and store it temporarily and then within the page just grab them from my temporary storage ?

Comment: @keewee279 10 query are not heavy, one hundred maybe yes, but not ten

Comment: you mean like pagination

Comment: @Ramki: No, the idea behind this is that I want to offer users to see certain parts of the website in different languages so depending on their selection I would then fetch from a different language column in the db and then use the items from there to be echoed out on the page - so on some pages this can be just 10 items but on others it might be 50.

Comment: @keewee279 fetch all you need but store them as a map (key value), that way you can easily access/use what you need

Comment: @Goikiu: Thanks - yes, this is exactly what I am looking for but I don't know how I have to adjust my PHP for this.